# templatetags vs custom template tags and filter in django

Tags: django

What is the difference between [templatetags like the simple_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) vs [the templatetag tag reference?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag). To better phrase my question, is the `templatetag` used for the purpose of Custom Template Tags and Filters or is it intended for another purpose entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [former](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) `templatetag` is used for creating custom functions that can be loaded and called in a template.  This is useful when you have a common task 
that needs to be executed, for example, generating a url that includes a querystring, when only given a namespace:

```
from django import template
from django.urls import reverse
from urllib.parse import urlencode

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def url_qs(context, namespace):
    url = reverse(namespace)
    return url + '?' + urlencode(context['querystring'])
```

the [latter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag) `templatetag` is used for escaping symbols that the Django template engine would interpret as a special character, eg. double brackets `{{`.  This version of templatetag is mostly useless, since you can just use [HTML escape codes](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html).

for example, if you want double brackets `{{`, using templatetag you have to do this:

```
{% templatetag openvariable %}
```

Or using escape codes:

```
&#123;&#123;
```

Comment: im confused on your response regarding the latter `templatetags`. your example for double quotes `&#123;&#123; ` doesn't use the `templatetag` [such as `{% templatetag openblock %} &#123;&#123; {% templatetag closeblock %}`] ?